# Perl regexp - retrieve all matchings to list and remove them from text

Tags: regex, perl

I have a text, where I would like find all matchings 
(e.g. every pattern which match `/d.g/` )

Those patterns I need in a list and removed from original text.

Operation on: `dog and dig where dug in dug` should give me:
(dog, dig, dug, dug).

The text should change to: `and  where in`

I could do It by passing the text twice, but it would be double work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'dog and dig where dug in dug';
my @matches;

$str =~ s/\b(d.g)\b/push @matches, $1; ''/ge;

print $str, "\n";
print join ', ', @matches;
```

Output:

```
 and  where  in 
dog, dig, dug, dug
```

Comment: Kenosis, can you explain the '' part of the regex (before `/ge`)?

Comment: @sputnick - The matches will be replaced by the last value in the substitution, so an empty string `''` is used.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this :

```
$_ = 'dog and dig where dug in dug';

(/\b(d.g)\b/) ? push @_, $1 : print "$_ " for split /\s+/;

print "\n\narr:\n", join "\n", @_;
```

## explanations

- `\b` is word boundaries
- `(condition) ? 'if true' : 'if false'` statement is a ternary operator

Comment: ANd how about retrieving the list of matchings?

Comment: Thnx, but that are TWO expressions, the first one does the erasing - the other retrieves matchings. I think I stated clearly, that I need an expression, which does both!

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'dog and dig where dug in dug';
my @matches;

push @matches, substr $str, $-[0], $+[0] - $-[0], '' while $str =~ /d.g/g;

print join(', ', @matches), "\n";

print $str, "\n";
```

**output**

```
dog, dig, dug, dug
 and  where  in
```